# VS2017 .Net Core 2.0 Tests: "Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, xunit, asp.net-core-2.0

I am not able to run any .Net Core tests on my machine from either the console, Test Explorer or from Resharper's Test Runner.

I have tried to break it down to the lowest possible level by creating a super basic test project.

Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0-preview-20170628-02" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Tests from the Xunit site:

```
using Xunit;

namespace MyFirstUnitTests
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void PassingTest()
        {
            Assert.Equal(4, Add(2, 2));
        }

        [Fact]
        public void FailingTest()
        {
            Assert.Equal(5, Add(2, 2));
        }

        int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

I get an inconclusive test result from Resharper's test runner and the Test Explorer shows no tests. To break it down even more I ran it with the following command (as administrator):

```
dotnet test -d:log.txt

D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1>dotnet test -d:log.txt
Build started, please wait...
Build completed.

Test run for D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\XUnitTestProject1.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.3.0-preview-20170628-02
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Starting test execution, please wait...
Logging Vstest Diagnostics in file: D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1\log.txt
Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process.
```

Output of log.txt file:

```
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:14.965, 3551183221240, vstest.console.dll, Using .Net Framework version:.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.003, 3551185524706, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginCache: Discovering the extensions using extension path.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.004, 3551185593428, vstest.console.dll, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHostRuntimeProvider: Resolving assembly.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.005, 3551185658770, vstest.console.dll, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHostRuntimeProvider: Resolved assembly. 
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.007, 3551185786618, vstest.console.dll, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.Trx.TestLogger: Resolving assembly.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.008, 3551185843983, vstest.console.dll, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.Trx.TestLogger: Resolved assembly. 
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.010, 3551185970715, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginCache: Discovered the extensions using extension path ''.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.010, 3551185976278, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginCache: Discoverers are ''.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.010, 3551185980015, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginCache: Executors are ''.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.010, 3551185983444, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginCache: Setting providers are ''.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.010, 3551185987135, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginCache: Loggers are ''.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.022, 3551186699491, vstest.console.dll, RunTestsArgumentProcessor:Execute: Test run is starting.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.022, 3551186706606, vstest.console.dll, RunTestsArgumentProcessor:Execute: Queuing Test run.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.022, 3551186729159, vstest.console.dll, TestRequestManager.RunTests: run tests started.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.034, 3551187444225, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginCache: Updating loadOnlyWellKnownExtensions from False to True.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.034, 3551187466435, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginCache: Using directories for assembly resolution 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\Extensions'.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.034, 3551187471502, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginCache: Updated the available extensions to 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.Trx.TestLogger.dll,C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\Extensions\Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHostRuntimeProvider.dll'.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.056, 3551188826402, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginManager.CreateTestExtension: Attempting to load test extension: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DefaultTestHostManager
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.056, 3551188855295, vstest.console.dll, TestPluginManager.CreateTestExtension: Attempting to load test extension: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.057, 3551188899226, vstest.console.dll, TestEngine: Initializing Parallel Execution as MaxCpuCount is set to: 1
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.096, 3551191372397, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Creating test run request.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.097, 3551191404509, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Starting.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.097, 3551191419508, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Starting run with settings:TestRunCriteria:
   KeepAlive=False,FrequencyOfRunStatsChangeEvent=10,RunStatsChangeEventTimeout=00:00:01.5000000,TestCaseFilter=,TestExecutorLauncher=
   Settingsxml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><RunSettings><RunConfiguration><ResultsDirectory>D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1\TestResults</ResultsDirectory><TargetPlatform>X86</TargetPlatform><TargetFrameworkVersion>.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion><TestAdaptersPaths>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\Extensions</TestAdaptersPaths></RunConfiguration></RunSettings>

TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.097, 3551191427533, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Wait for the first run request is over.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.099, 3551191519017, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync: Started.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.099, 3551191527717, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest.WaitForCompletion: Waiting with timeout -1.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.099, 3551191555935, vstest.console.dll, ProxyParallelExecutionManager: Triggering test run for next source: D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\XUnitTestProject1.dll
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.100, 3551191579325, vstest.console.dll, ProxyExecutionManager: Test host is non shared. Lazy initialize.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.135, 3551193757033, vstest.console.dll, Listening on port : 50705
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.151, 3551194809169, vstest.console.dll, DotnetTestHostmanager: Full path of dotnet.exe is C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.152, 3551194824010, vstest.console.dll, DotnetTestHostmanager: Adding  --runtimeconfig "D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\XUnitTestProject1.runtimeconfig.json" in args
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.152, 3551194830856, vstest.console.dll, DotnetTestHostmanager: Adding  --depsfile "D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\XUnitTestProject1.deps.json" in args
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.152, 3551194841633, vstest.console.dll, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel: Resolving assembly.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.153, 3551194896353, vstest.console.dll, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel: Resolved assembly. 
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.153, 3551194915124, vstest.console.dll, DotnetTestHostmanager: Reading file D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\XUnitTestProject1.deps.json to get path of testhost.dll
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.214, 3551198699580, vstest.console.dll, DotnetTestHostmanager: Relative path of testhost.dll with respect to package folder is microsoft.testplatform.testhost/15.3.0-preview-20170628-02\lib/netstandard1.5/testhost.dll
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.220, 3551199070691, vstest.console.dll, DotnetTestHostmanager: Looking for path microsoft.testplatform.testhost/15.3.0-preview-20170628-02\lib/netstandard1.5/testhost.dll in folder D:\Users\myusername\.dotnet\store\|arch|\|tfm|
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.329, 3551205886619, vstest.console.dll, DotnetTestHostmanager: Looking for path microsoft.testplatform.testhost/15.3.0-preview-20170628-02\lib/netstandard1.5/testhost.dll in folder D:\Users\myusername\.nuget\packages
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:21:15.329, 3551205902011, vstest.console.dll, DotnetTestHostmanager: Full path of testhost.dll is D:\Users\myusername\.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.testhost/15.3.0-preview-20170628-02\lib/netstandard1.5/testhost.dll
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 6, 2017/11/10, 09:21:17.200, 3551322870967, vstest.console.dll, DotnetTestHostManager: Starting process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' with command line 'exec --runtimeconfig "D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\XUnitTestProject1.runtimeconfig.json" --depsfile "D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\XUnitTestProject1.deps.json" "D:\Users\myusername\.nuget\packages\microsoft.testplatform.testhost/15.3.0-preview-20170628-02\lib/netstandard1.5/testhost.dll" --port 50705 --parentprocessid 8020 --diag "D:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\XUnitTestProject1\XUnitTestProject1\log.host.17-11-10_09-21-15_14353_4.txt"'
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 6, 2017/11/10, 09:21:17.283, 3551328037248, vstest.console.dll, Test Runtime launched with Pid: 2040
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:22:17.288, 3555078346047, vstest.console.dll, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources: Resolving assembly.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:22:17.289, 3555078412364, vstest.console.dll, AssemblyResolver: Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.resources: Resolving assembly.
TpTrace Error: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:22:17.437, 3555087661572, vstest.console.dll, ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun: Failed to start test run: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1 sources)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.InitializeExtensions(IEnumerable`1 sources)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:22:17.660, 3555101595901, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest:SendTestRunMessage: Starting.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:22:17.660, 3555101622579, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest:SendTestRunMessage: Completed.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:22:21.015, 3555311310893, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest:TestRunComplete: Starting. IsAborted:False IsCanceled:False.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 4, 2017/11/10, 09:22:21.058, 3555313975900, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest:TestRunComplete: Completed.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:22:21.058, 3555314000966, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest.Dispose: Starting.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:22:21.059, 3555314006561, vstest.console.dll, TestRunRequest.Dispose: Completed.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:22:21.059, 3555314011940, vstest.console.dll, TestRequestManager.RunTests: run tests completed, sucessful: True.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:22:21.059, 3555314016720, vstest.console.dll, RunTestsArgumentProcessor:Execute: Test run is completed.
TpTrace Verbose: 0 : 8020, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:22:21.059, 3555314021368, vstest.console.dll, Executor.Execute: Exiting with exit code of 1
```

Output of log.host.txt file

```
TpTrace Information: 0 : 2040, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:17.796, 3551360175838, testhost.dll, DefaultEngineInvoker: Monitoring parent process with id: '8020'
TpTrace Information: 0 : 2040, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:17.904, 3551366851646, testhost.dll, DefaultEngineInvoker: Initialize communication on port number: '50705'
TpTrace Information: 0 : 2040, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:17.911, 3551367314294, testhost.dll, Trying to connect to server on port : 50705
TpTrace Information: 0 : 2040, 2, 2017/11/10, 09:21:17.984, 3551371828147, testhost.dll, DefaultEngineInvoker: Start Request Processing.
TpTrace Information: 0 : 2040, 5, 2017/11/10, 09:21:23.051, 3551688508968, testhost.dll, DefaultEngineInvoker: RequestHandler timed out while connecting to the Sender.
```

I have tried the following simple approaches:

- Restarting VS
- Restarting my machine
- Creating NUnit tests, MSTests
- Running everything as administrator
- Updating all the libraries
- Reverting the libraries to older versions that are in the the tutorials
- My .Net 4.6.1 project's tests are running successfully so I think it is only .net core
- Checked the windows logs for odd exceptions

Any assistance or leads would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am working on an amazon workspace so it may affect this in some way that I don't know yet.

Comment: You might want to report this as a bug at https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues if you don't get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your SDK version from:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0-preview-20170628-02" />
```

to:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0" />
```

And update your .net core to the latest version.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, I tried it, even updated it to 15.5 yesterday, still failed.

Comment: plus one: that solved the issue for me (upgraded to a later version instead of back to an older one).